# How to download junit from sonatype?

Tags: maven, junit, sonatype

I was trying to download junit following some videos on youtube, but it seems the videos are out dated. The maven web pages of search results have become completely different and I couldn't find a download button.

I found I might need the nexus repositary manager to download things like using github desktop? But I don't have a business email address to register. And I guess it doesn't work that way

So how exactly could I download a thing from sonatype? I didn't know downloading a junit would be this much complicated and torturing. I don't understand why they made it this way...

Comment: Can you link the videos? How have you called Maven? How does your pom file look like?

Comment: @khmarbaise I just searched how to install junit and checked the first two. They've been out-dated. I've downloaded the files from somewhere else. And later I found on Sonatype that they've put files in the Browse button under versions.

Comment: @khmarbaise I didn't really use Maven, it's just the web pages of Sonatype.

Comment: Why not using Maven it will do the download automatically... just add it to the pom file and that's it... BTW: here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/. you can find all aritfacts if you really like to manually download all of the things you need that's a crazy work...

Comment: https://central.sonatype.com/search?namespace=junit&sort=name click on the button "View All" (upper right) .. you will be going to this page: `https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.13.2/versions` and then clock on the line where `Browse` is given and you will be here: `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.13.2/` where you can download the jar file manually if you really like to... But I recommend not to go that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not like the old pages, they had very obvious download buttons directly on the right side. They've now put the files under: Versions -> Browse [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02vbR.png)

If anyone else is following the old videos to download the necessary .jar files, this could help you download them.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jar files directly from this URL:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/